# Incorrect FloatingActionButton layout margins on Android that's below 5.0

Tags: android, android-design-library

Cannot understand why my floating action button has margin like 32dp instead 16dp?

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
```

On Android 5.0 (emulator) all is correct but on Android 4.3 (real device) margins is too large. Although root layout hasn't paddings or margins.

P.S. FloatActionButton from Google design library.

[image: Android 4.3 Screenshot]

Comment: Isn't it because on 5.0 FAB's shadow is being drawn on FAB's layer outside its bounds and on 4.3 FAB's shadow is just a part of FAB's background?

Comment: I understood it but in the blank project in wizard all is correct although it sets margins too. But there is  a coordinator layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way apparently to achieve this, is using a an API-specific styles. In your normal values/styles.xml, put something like this:

```
<style name="floating_action_button">
<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginRight">8dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
```

Then under **values-v21/styles.xml**, use this:

```
<style name="floating_action_button">
<item name="android:layout_margin">16dp</item>
```

Finally, apply the style to your FloatingActionButton :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
...
style="@style/floating_action_button"
...
/>
```

As  Zielony have noted, in API <20, the button renders its own shadow, which adds to the overall logical width of the view, whereas in API >=20 it uses the new Elevation parameters which don't contribute to the view width.

Comment: Thank you! I know about it. Just I hoped that it has another solution(